# I wanted to add text and arrow on a circle

Tags: tkz-euclide

I wanted to draw a circle with text and arrow like the one on this picture.
[image]

But I don't know how to do that using tkz-euclide.

I already did something like this

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(150:2){A}
\tkzDefPoint(330:2){B}
\tkzDefPoint(20:2){C}

\tkzDefPoint(268:2){D}

\tkzDefMidPoint(A,C)    \tkzGetPoint{e}
\tkzDefMidPoint(B,D)    \tkzGetPoint{f}

\tkzDrawSegments(A,B O,D O,C B,D O,e O,f)
\tkzMarkRightAngles(O,e,A O,f,D)

\tkzDrawSector[fill=gray!20](O,B)(C)

\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,2cm)
\filldraw[fill=gray!10] 
     (150:2cm)
  -- (20:2cm)  
  arc[start angle=20, end angle=150, radius=2cm] 
  -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I add text with arrow pointing to the things on that circle?

Comment: You could just use `tikz` directly: For example `\draw [thick, red, latex-] (80:1.5) -- (80:2.5) node [above]  {tembereng};`.  Adjust the coordinates as desired.

Comment: @masrosid please have a look athe answer below if it suits the requirement

Comment: oke. I"ll try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this --to remove the box around the text delete the `draw` option in

```
\draw[{Latex}-] ($(O)!0.5!(f)$)--++(0:2cm)node[draw, right, fill=orange!30, font =\tiny]{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2cm}@{}}
        some text added here\\
\end{tabular}};
```

[image]

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(150:2){A}
\tkzDefPoint(330:2){B}
\tkzDefPoint(20:2){C}

\tkzDefPoint(268:2){D}

\tkzDefMidPoint(A,C)    \tkzGetPoint{e}
\tkzDefMidPoint(B,D)    \tkzGetPoint{f}

\tkzDrawSegments(A,B O,D O,C B,D O,e O,f)
\tkzMarkRightAngles(O,e,A O,f,D)

\tkzDrawSector[fill=gray!20](O,B)(C)

\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,2cm)
\filldraw[fill=gray!10] 
     (150:2cm)
  -- (20:2cm)  
  arc[start angle=20, end angle=150, radius=2cm] 
  -- cycle;
%\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,D,e,f,O)
\draw[{Latex}-] ($(O)!0.5!(f)$)--++(0:2cm)node[draw, right, fill=orange!30, font =\tiny]{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2cm}@{}}
        some text added here\\
\end{tabular}};
\draw[{Latex}-] ($(A)!0.5!(e)$)--++(45:2cm)--++(2,0cm)node[draw, right, fill=orange!30, font =\tiny]{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2cm}@{}}
        some text added here\\
\end{tabular}};
\draw[{Latex}-] ($(C)!0.5!(B)$)--++(45:1cm)--++(4pt,0cm)node[draw, right, fill=orange!30, font =\tiny]{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2cm}@{}}
        some text added here\\
\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. I will try that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use tikz directly: For example, `\draw [thick, red, latex-] (80:1.5) - (80:2.5) node [above] {tembereng};`. Adjust the coordinates as needed.

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SE. This was already suggested by @Peter Grill.